# Schema compare not working with composite project

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a data base that I've setup using composite SQL Data projects in SQL Server 2012. The main database has a reference to a library database and that reference is set to include in the same database. I can deploy it fine. However, when I try to do a compare, it ignores the library database. Is there some setting I need use to get it to compare to the full, composed database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/06/26/composite-projects-and-schema-compare.aspx

> To deploy a composite project you must set the Include composite objects option on the project you're deploying from. ... This is available as an Advanced option in Publish and on the Debug properties tab, and as a **general option in Schema Compare**

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that option.